# d3 not defined, however it works on the in browser console

Tags: html, node.js, d3.js

I am using node.js and trying to us the d3.js module, but it says it is not defined when the page loads. However, in the browser console I can access d3 functionality, so I'm quite confused.

This is happening across Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

The link on the backend is hooked up like so:

```
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + 'public/scripts'));
```

html (tried top and bottom parts of the page):

```
<script src='/js/d3.min.js'></script>
```

In-html script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var width = 700;
        var height = 580;
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height);
 </script>
```

When calling d3 the console logs: `blank.html:394 Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined`

[image: But d3 works in the console.]

Is this a bug? Or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Is your script loaded on the top, or on the bottom of the file?

Comment: I've tried both top and bottom, but it behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake. When I tried to change the placement of the `<script src='/js/d3.min.js'></script>` I put it inside this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<![endif]-->
```

So, now it is like this and it works:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```